# how to check for existence params in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form for filtered search:

```
<%= form_tag admin_publications_path, method: "get", id: "filter", class: "filter" do %>
  <%= label_tag "Category" %>
  <%= select "publication", "category", options_for_select(options_for_categories, selected: params[:publication][:category]), {prompt: 'All'}, onchange: "$('#filter').submit();" %>
<% end %>
```

this works fine as long as there as params[:publication][:category] is available.

But if the params are not available, for instance when the view is rendered without previous search, I get the error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Is there a way to check from the view if the params are present?

thanks for your help,

Anthony

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Views should NOT know about `params`.
In controller (or view helper) create variable like `

`if params[:publication]
  @selected = params[:publication][:category] 
end`

or even do it in 1 line

`@selected = params[:publication].try(:[], :category)`

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
<% if params[:publication].present? %>
```

Comment: __if params[:publication]__ 
more clean

Answer (score 0):

Use `fetch`.  The second parameter will be the returned value when `params[:publication]` is not present.

```
params.fetch(:publication, {})[:category]
```

Be warned though that the following will raise an exception

```
params = { publication: nil }
params.fetch(:publication, {})[:category] # NoMethodError nil.[]
```